# Strange behaviour in google map after format my computer

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I have generated a Google Maps API key for my Android application. It works perfectly fine.

```
Before some days ago i format my computer,but i stored my map api key.
```

Now when i apply this in my another android project strangely, the map view doesn't display anything but empty grids.

Note that I've allowed all the permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: i havent faced such issue..but why dont you create new key..cause the keystore file got deleted and when you build any project it got recreated..so with existing(now) keystore file try generate map key and see you getting any differece or not..

Comment: Before format my pc i also backup my keystore file using that i m signed apk to upload on marekt. using that i generate my api key but its not working.

Comment: it might be working with signed copy of apk..have you tried sign any app and then run on device?

Comment: is it possible to work with unsigned apk ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to regenerate the MD5 Fingerprint in order to resolve this issue. as your debug.keystore is now different.